# Modeling a cave/tunnel system

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, sculpting

I'm trying to model a cave system in 3d.

I am an avid caver and have an insight on the structure of a particular cave. Also, I have sketches of it as reference.

I've been trying different techniques, but I have been focusing mostly using curves (bezier curves in particular) to somehow plan out the general structure as sort of tunnels and then perhaps work with the different rooms/adjoining passages to resize the structure in accordance with my memory/sketches.

I worked on the idea of using a bezier circle and use it as a bevel object to follow the curve in order to form a tube-like structure.

But this I find complicated because I haven't found a way to sort of "branch out" the tubes to accommodate the different junctions in the cave.

And anyway.. even if this were achieved, I would end out with a uniform tube-like general structure which is not what I want. I'd need to work on it extensively to open up and model e.g. the different caverns within.

I would prefer to work with cave system dynamically so if changes need to be made to the length/positions of each "branch"/ size of caverns etc that they can be changed in an efficient manner.

Remember that this is not a "flat" cave - the passages stretch upwards/downwards and in all directions including corridors, large caverns, shafts and fissures.

Grateful for any techniques for structuring caves/tunnels.

Thank you.

[image: the cave system from above]

[image: cave system from the side view]

Comment: You can use different splines for the cave branches, then you can merge them by applying a Remesh modifier to the curve object. Alternative option is to trace the cross-section of the caves as 2D shape. Then remesh the solidified shape and apply Inflate using the Cloth Filter in Sculpt mode.